# Understanding stdout output when used with fork()

Tags: c

Here is my C program :

```
int main() {
    fork();
    printf("one ");
    fork();
    printf("two ");
}
```

The output is :

```
one two one two one two one two
```

However, If I change the code and add a `\n` to the print statement   :

```
int main() {
    fork();
    printf("one\n");
    fork();
    printf("two\n");
}
```

The output is :

```
one
one
two
two
two
two
```

Or sometimes (the order can change) :

```
one
two
one
two
two
two
```

Why is the output `8` words in the first program and `6` in the second?

Comment: stdout is line buffered. But it doesn't matter because process execution order is arbitrary anyway, so it could happen in any order.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem.    What explanation have YOU considered?

Comment: This isn't a homework problem :) I want to understand buffer overwriting if happening here.

Answer (score 1):

2 processes execute the first `printf()`, and then 4 processes execute the second `printf()`, so there should be 6 output.

In the first code, it seems `fork()` is executed before what is in the buffer is flushed, then the contents of buffer is duplicated and then excess output appeared.

In the second code, it seems `\n` had it flush the buffer and therefore no excess output appeared.